# Let $T:V\rightarrow U$ be a linear transformation. If $dimKerT=k$ and $ B=(b_1,...,b_n)$ is a basis of $V$, then prove the following statement:

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Let $T:V\rightarrow U$ be a linear transformation. Prove/disprove: If $dimKerT=k$ and $ B=(b_1,...,b_n)$ is a basis of $V$, then in the set $(Tb_1,...Tb_n)$ there are exactly $k$ vectors that can be expressed as linear combinations of the previous vectors.

Hey everyone. This statement seems correct. First, we note that $dimImT$ is $n-k$.

If $k=0$, then $KerT=\{0\}$, hence $T$ is an injection- which implies $(Tb_1,...,Tb_n)$ is a linear independent set (for any injective linear transformation $F:V\rightarrow U$, $S$ is a linear independent set iff $F(S)$ is linearly independent), and in particular a basis of $V$- therefore it has exactly $0$ vectors which are linear combinations of the previous vectors, just as $dimKerT$.

Else, $k\gt 0$ and we have $|(Tb_1,...,Tb_n)|\gt dimImT=n-k$ (number of vectors in $T(B)$ is greater than $n-k$), hence is a linear dependent set. I want to prove it has *exactly* $k$ vectors that can be expressed as linear combinations of the previous vectors, and not at least, but am not sure how. 
Would love to get some help or hints on that one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a question that is more of vocabulary than of theory.  Does $\begin{bmatrix} 1&2\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$ have one vector that can be expressed as a liner combination of the other, or are both vectors described as linear combinations of the others?

Comment: How can the dimension of $(Tb_1,\dots,Tb_n)$ be larger than the image of $T$?

Comment: @DougM Yes I should really edit the post to be more clear, in your example there is one which can be expressed as a linear combination of the others- "others" refers to the vectors that are ahead of the given one.. so basically $k$ vectors that can be expressed as linear combinations of the previous vectors.

Comment: @mobiuseng Yes I meant the cardinality, number of vectors in $(Tb_1,...,Tb_n)$ is greater than $dimImT$, not the dimension of the span of the set...

Comment: Now, consider the span! :) (how it was already done in the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim\langle Tb_1,\ldots,Tb_n\rangle=n-k$. And, if you have $n$ vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$, asserting that they span a space with dimension $n-k$ is equivalent to the assertion that there is a set of $k$ vectors of $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ which are linear combinations of the remaining  vectors and that no set with more than $k$ vectors has that property.